# Excel VBA setting named cell formula using range property

Tags: vba, excel, range, formula

hoping you can help. Banging my head against the wall at this point. Fairly new to writing VBA. I have some VBA code listed below. Essentially, what I am trying to do is lock/unlock, change fill color, and set formula for a range of cells based on the input from a drop down menu using the worksheet change event and ActiveSheet. The code lives on the sheet itself. Everything works fine except for the formula setting piece.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With ActiveSheet
.Unprotect Password:="somepw"
    If Range("d17").Value = "Yes" Then
        .Range("D22:D78").Locked = False
        .Range("D22:D78").Interior.Color = RGB(115, 246, 42)
        .Range("Inc_06PCTotRev").Formula = "=SUM($D$22:$D$25)"
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("d22:D78")) <> 0 Then
        If .Range("D22").Locked = True Then
            With Range("D22:D78")
                .Locked = False
                .ClearContents
                .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
            End With
        Else:  .Range("D22:D78").ClearContents
        End If
    Else: .Range("D22:D78").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
          .Range("D22:D78").Locked = True
    End If
.Protect Password:="somepw"
End With
End Sub
```

When that is included I receive an error stating "method range of object _worksheet failed" and excel crashes. If I comment it out it fires without issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if this isn't specific enough or doesn't make sense and I'll try my best to expand.

Comment: is the named range a workbook or worksheet named range?

Comment: Each time you add that formula you are again calling the worksheet change event.  I am guessing you are ending up in an Eternal loop

Comment: What does the name range represent, IE what is the actual range?

Comment: You could disable events when you start your Worksheet_Change code, and enable it again in the end.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That's exactly what I ended up doing and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I posted in my comments you are in a never ending loop because you change your worksheet in the worksheet change event.  You need to keep track of the change call.  Can alleviate this by creating a variable to keep track of when you called the change, this also is assuming that the name range is 1 cell.

```
Public bRunning As Boolean 'keeps track of when we are making the change

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    bRunning = False 'set to false when the sheet is activated
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If bRunning = False Then 'check to see if this is the first change
    bRunning = True 'set the variable letting us know we are making the change.
    With ActiveSheet

    .Unprotect Password:="somepw"
        If Range("d17").Value = "Yes" Then
        .Range("D22:D78").Locked = False
        .Range("D22:D78").Interior.Color = RGB(115, 246, 42)
        .Range("Inc_06PCTotRev").Formula = "=SUM($D$22:$D$25)"
        ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("d22:D78")) <> 0 Then
        If .Range("D22").Locked = True Then
            With Range("D22:D78")
            .Locked = False
            .ClearContents
            .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
            End With
        Else:  .Range("D22:D78").ClearContents
        End If
        Else: .Range("D22:D78").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
          .Range("D22:D78").Locked = True
        End If
    .Protect Password:="somepw"
    End With
    Else
    bRunning = False 'reset the variable as we are done making changes
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Stepped away for a while, but damn. Thanks a lot. Feel a bit foolish. Completely understand the crash part at this point. Was updating cell properties in the code previously and completely missed that those didn't generate a perpetual loop since they didn't alter the cell contents. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Spoke too soon. This actually didn't end up working for me because the formula piece is actually set for multiple cells, not just one. However, did end up getting the code to work. Added Application.EnableEvents = False to the beginning and Application.EnableEvents = True to the end as well as an Error handler to set the value to true on error. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to perform a SUM when your routine is called, you can use the `Worksheet.Sum function`:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("$D$22:$D$25"))
```

If you actually need a formula in that cell, consider using the `FormulaR1C1 function`:

```
.Range("Inc_06PCTotRev").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(...)"
```

Lookup FormulaR1C1 in under Excel help to gain a better understanding of the R1C1 referencing syntax. If the cell you want to insert the formula in is `$D$26`, you would replace the "..." above with "R[-4]C:R[-1]C". If the formula is supposed to be in cell $E$20, you would replace the "..." above with "R[2]C[-1]:R[5]C[-1]".

R[#] references the # of rows from the destination range/cell and C[#] referenced the # columns from the destination range/cell.